# VT-x in windows 10 always be set as disabled when restart the system

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bios, 64-bit, virtualization

all,

I see this question is discussed many time. But my situation is a little bit different. I CAN NOT SAVE to enable the VT-x and VT-d from BIOS. Normally, after I enable them from BIOS, and press F10, then system will asked whether save the new setting, and I select "Yes". But after reboot, the VirtalBox still can not create a 64bit system. And when I go back to check BIOS setting, the VT-x and VT-d are still disabled. So I do not know how can I save the setting of enable VT-X and VT-d. I think there maybe some protection of the BIOS modification. I use windows 10 pro, 64bit system.

Thanks
Zhihong

Comment: Did you disable hypervisor in Windows to run VirtualBox?

Comment: Biswa, my HyperV is by default disabled.

Comment: Hi, Biswa, just did a test. Because by default, my HyperV is disabled, so I planned to first enable it, try to enable VT-x and VT-d. And it works, and I even did not disable HyperV back, and the 64 bit system is available in VirtualBox. Thanks for the hint!!!

Comment: Don't disable the Hyper-V feature from `dism` command or from `OptionalFeatures.exe`. Disable only the hypervisor with command:: `bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off`.

Comment: Biswa, thanks for the further info with disable Hyper-V. I do not know how my Hyper-V is disabled, and also do not not the difference yet. But will google to check it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For my issue in windows pro 10, later I figure out as discussed above. And then can get the 64 bit system in VirtualBox (only have 32 bit system in Virtalbox is my original issue):

1. Enable HyperV. It is disabled by default in my Windows 10 pro. Windows search -> Turn Windows features on or off->Enable HyperV, and only the "Hyper-V Management tool" will be checked.

[image]

2. From the BIOS (HP EliteBook), enable VT-x and VT-d. The "enable" action can be saved now!!! The exact location is: BIOS setup->Advanced->System Options.

[image]